# perpetual bond that yields 0%

Tags: bonds, economics

As far as I understand perpetual bonds are endless and don't mature.
So why would anybody invest in one that does not yield?
You don't know when/if they are going to pay.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a bond?

Comment: some perpetuals do get  redeemed recently the UK retired some consols dating back to the Napoleonic wars.

Comment: @Pepone The Consols paid no interest?

Comment: @DilipSarwate no why would a bond not have a coupon

Comment: @Pepone You seemed to be pointing out consols as examples of the perpetual  no-coupon no-interest bonds that the OP was talking about, and saying that consols _were_ redeemed recently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only heard of zero yield perpetual bond in the context of a trick interview question. They would ask how much would you pay for a perpetual zero coupon bond.

The idea is you would pay zero for it since you don't get any coupons, and you never get your money back.